# How to open file's under my app's document folder with other app on ios?

Tags: iphone, ipad, file, sharing

I found some app could open files with other app on ios.  Such as open an avi file with other video player.

How can I do this?  Will ios copy the file to the sandbox of other app?

Answer (score 3):

I'd suggest reading this earlier answer and responses;

[how-do-i-associate-file-types-with-an-iphone-application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2774343/how-do-i-associate-file-types-with-an-iphone-application)

Answer (score 1):

An iPhone app is not allow to modify or access anything outside its sandbox.

And even if you access it by some means, your app will not be approved by Apple.

Also it won't work if your device is not jailbroken.

You can refer to this link and decide what you want to do.

http://blogs.oreilly.com/iphone/2008/09/sandbox-think-like-apple.html

Hope this helps you. :)

Comment: The link seems to be broken.